# Running Android TTS in a Service

Tags: android, text-to-speech, android-service

I'm trying to get Android's TTS to run inside a service, but I have no idea why it isn't working, it compiles, doesn't crash, but it just doesn't work.

The Toast notification do work though.

```
package alarm.test;

import android.app.Service;
import com.google.tts.TextToSpeechBeta;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAlarmService extends Service {

    private TextToSpeechBeta myTts;
    private TextToSpeechBeta.OnInitListener ttsInitListener = new TextToSpeechBeta.OnInitListener() {
        public void onInit( int arg0, int arg1 ) {
            myTts.speak("", 0, null);
        }
    };

@Override
public void onCreate() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    myTts = new TextToSpeechBeta( this,
            ttsInitListener );

 Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    myTts.speak("something is working", TextToSpeechBeta.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
 Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onBind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onDestroy();
 Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onDestroy()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onStart(intent, startId);
 Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onUnbind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

}
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you mean by "don't work". What do you see on LogCat?

Comment: DEBUG/TextToSpeechBeta(512): TextToSpeechBeta not instled - dfauing to basic platform TextToSpeech for speak
VERBOSE/TtsSice(418): TTS service received 
INFO/TtsService(418): Stoping
INFO/TtsService(418): Stopped
VERBOSE/TtsService(418): TTS procesing: 
VERBOSE/TtsService(418): TtsService.setLanguage(eng, USA, )
INFO/SVOX Pico Engine(418): Language already loaded (en-US == en-US)
DEBUG/dalvikvm(68): GC_CONCURRENT freed 719K, 48% free 4093K/7751K, external 2041K/2378K, paused 21ms+27ms
DEBUG/SntpClient(68): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Answer (score 16):

You can do like below: It's working for me.
You have to create an activity to start this service, like this: this.startService(intent)

```
public class TTSService extends Service implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{

private String str;
private TextToSpeech mTts;
private static final String TAG="TTSService";

@Override

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return null;
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {

      mTts = new TextToSpeech(this,
                this  // OnInitListener
                );
      mTts.setSpeechRate(0.5f);
      Log.v(TAG, "oncreate_service");
     str ="turn left please ";
    super.onCreate();
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if (mTts != null) {
            mTts.stop();
            mTts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {


    sayHello(str);

    Log.v(TAG, "onstart_service");
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    Log.v(TAG, "oninit");
     if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            int result = mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA ||
                result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Language is not available.");
            } else {

                sayHello(str);

            }
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "Could not initialize TextToSpeech.");
        }
}
private void sayHello(String str) {
      mTts.speak(str,
                TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, 
                null);
}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeechService.html

since API Level 14, android has added a default TextToSpeech Service class that does what you want.