# Android Text-to- Speech not working for loop

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am trying to run Text to Speech in service and while a single string runs perfectly(`tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,null);`
), it's not working when I try to run it using for loop. Any help would be appreciated.

```
for (String a :arr) 
{
     tts.speak(a, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null, null);
     tts.playSilentUtterance(1000, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);

}
```

Comment: what "does not work"? does one call to `tts.speak` work? so you should hear at least the first string in `arr`, shouldn't you?

Comment: Only if i call speak function once like the call specifically stated in question does it work otherwise in the loop it doesn't say anything.

Comment: i just used deprecated methods since i was testing on 4.4 and it works with no problems

Comment: the deprecated methods didn't help. please refer the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219568/running-android-tts-in-a-service and let me know do they work with this. Check the solution by coastline.

Comment: Don't use null in all of the parameters, it can cause problems. Try using the API correctly

Answer (score 0):

Implement `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener` and inside the `onInit` function do something like below:

```
override fun onInit(status: Int) = if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        val result: Int = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault())
        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED
        ) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Language not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        // Wait 2 seconds to tell the first name
        // Add some silence between the names
        val arrayOfStrings = arrayOf(
            caller_name_label.text.toString(),
            caller_name_label.text.toString(),
            caller_name_label.text.toString()
        )
        var i = 0
        for (name in arrayOfStrings) {

            lifecycleScope.launch {
                delay(2000L)

                textToSpeech.speak(arrayOfStrings[i], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null, null)
                textToSpeech.playSilentUtterance(2000L, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);

                i += 1
            }
        }


    } else {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Init failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

use it and let me know

```
 TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
 tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
 for (String a :arr) 
{
 tts.speak("Text to say aloud", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
 }
```